# Changing height of <p> block to a fixed height equal to that of auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to make a show more / show less button which changes the height of a `<p>` block and slides to the correct size.

I know this can be done, and can only be done, between two fixed heights and the use of `auto` will stop the animation.

**My question:**

How can I get the `px` value of the auto height for the `<p>` block before the animation starts so that the height can be set to this `<p>` block explicitly for the animation to occur.

So far I am using:

```
function popupShow(id) {

    var curCss = $('#results').find('a#'+id).parent().find('p').css("height");
    var parent = $('#results').find('a#'+id).parent();

    if(curCss == "136px") {
        parent.find('p').css("height", "auto");
        parent.find('a.show').html("...Show Less");
    }
    else {
        parent.find('p').css("height", "136px");
        parent.find('a.show').html("...Show More");
    }

}
```

which works great how amending the size of the `<p>` to include the full text however I want to add in some animation. Following some googling I changed this too

```
function popupShow(id) {
    var curCss = $('#results').find('a#'+id).parent().find('p').css("max-height");
    var parent = $('#results').find('a#'+id).parent();

    if(curCss == "136px") {
        parent.find('p').css("max-height", "500px");
        parent.find('a.show').html("...Show Less");
    }
    else {
        parent.find('p').css("max-height", "136px");
        parent.find('a.show').html("...Show More");
    }
}
```

However I have noticed some blog posts can be bigger than `500px` so I set it to `5000px` as it said *anything bigger than what you actually need* but then the animation looks stupid.

For the css animation I am using:

```
-webkit-transition: max-height 0.8s;
-moz-transition: max-height 0.8s;
transition: max-height 0.8s;
```

html layout for 1 blog post (ignore php):

```
<div class="post-hold">
    <div class="p-head">
        <div class="p-title">
            ' . $posts[$i]['title'] . '
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-body">
        <p>' . $posts[$i]['description'] . '</p>
        <a id="' . $posts[$i]['id'] . '" class="show" onClick="popupShow(this.id)">...show more</a>
        <div style="display: block; clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-foot">
        <div class="info">
            <span class="p-time">' . \Core\View::time_since($posts[$i]['timeStamp']) . '</span>
            <span class="p-user">' . $posts[$i]['user'] . '</span>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block; clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vh5bfgg/) for the 136px -> 500px example.

Comment: Can you show a live example on Codepen or JSFiddle?

Comment: @makshh i'll make one now

Comment: @makshh jsfiddle in edit of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use line-height (no need to know height):

```css
p {
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  line-height:0em;
  transition:0.25s
}
a:hover + p , 
p:hover /* don't loose p once you want to hover it/select text or click an inside link */
{
  line-height:1.2em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
<a href="#">link</a>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
```

Comment: This looks lovely however i start with a fixed height, say 150px then this needs to expand to the auto size which can be anything depending on the length of the text. Could this still be applied?

Comment: do you have an example ? in this case , you should wrap part of text to hide into a span and apply the line-height transition to that part of text only. This could be done from server side keeping/spliting a text-length visible

Comment: Am trying to get a jsfiddle working but keeps saying my function is not defined so am working on it haha.

Comment: @Matt okay,  here is the last span idea http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBZgNq  What you have done is what css can do for an height, to retrieve real height javascript is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide paragraph in JS, get height and show again.

JS:

```
var p = $('p');
var pMaxHeight = $('p').css('max-height');

$(window).resize(function() {
  p.css({
    position: "absolute",
    visibility: "hidden",
    display: "block",
    maxHeight: 'none'
  });
  pHeight = p.height();
  p.css({
    position: "",
    visibility: "",
    display: "",
    maxHeight: '150px'
  });
});

$(window).trigger('resize');

$('button').click(function() {
  pMaxHeight = $('p').css('max-height');
  if (pMaxHeight == '150px') {
    p.css('max-height', pHeight);
  } else {
    p.css('max-height', '150px');
  }
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/BzWXzO)

Comment: This one works perfectly too. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Yes, but now I realized that it will not work when you change the width of the screen (paragraph gets higher on smaller screens).

Comment: Ah yes I see that now

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking if you need get an element's height or width use the  .offsetWidth and .offsetHeight properties.

Please note that the .offsetWidth and .offsetHeight properties belong to the element not the .style.

Example:

var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight;

Answer (score 0):

[Show more show less with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566137/show-more-show-less-with-jquery)

This should toggle the showing of the full div by clicking the actual div, you can add the click event to any trigger you want.

HTML:

```
<p id="blah">
    Long...Content
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#blah').css({height:'20px', overflow:'hidden'});
$('#blah').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('open')) {
        $this.animate({height:'20px'});
        $this.data('open', 0);

    }
    else {
        $this.animate({height:'100%'});
        $this.data('open', 1);
    }
});
```

Showing less with javascript initially will not hide the div indefinitely for users w/o javascript enabled.